# Am I being hacked? Mac group name “wheel” in Get Info not found in System > Users and Groups

Tags: mac, permissions, privacy

I was using Get Info in the Finder to check the available space on my internal drive this morning and noticed in Sharing & Permissions at the bottom that the Group option was assigned to `wheel`. I am a solopreneur and have nothing related to `wheel`. I checked System Preferences>Users and Groups, but did not see a group named "wheel".

I share office space with somebody that enters my office every night and re-organizes its contents -- she has a serious case of OCD for which I sympathize. The last name of her IT contractor has `wheel` as the first part of their name. We are not on the same network and do not share internet services. Naturally, it makes me wonder if my privacy is being violated.

Is there a way to make sure that her OCD has not led to an invasion of privacy? How can I check to see if they are using my router and/or ISP?

Comment: You are not being hacked.  `wheel` group exists on every Linux and Unix based operating system.

Comment: Also, if you were being hacked, why would a hacker leave an obvious clue? If you were being hacked you wouldn’t know until something serious happened. In general, whenever someone posts on Super User about them being “hacked” that is utterly never the case.

Comment: That is good to know. I don't remember the name of the group being "wheel", but I will take your word for it.